# Trying to launch a program using pycharm

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess
first_command: str = input("Hello sir. Would you like for me to do anything?> ")
if str(first_command) == str("JARVIS Open Spotify" or "Hey Jarvis open spotify" or "Open spotify" or "launch spotify"):
    subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Spotify.exe
```

(sorry if this is a stupid question ive just started programming)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want help with setting configuration to run the file in Pycharm?

Comment: 1) You have a SyntaxError in the `Popen` call 2) Duplicate: [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `if` statement is not correct, or not what I assume you intend it to be like.

The `input()` function always returns a string, so there is no need to use the `str(...)` beforehand.

Secondly, this statement also returns the first `str` (from left to right) that is not empty. So

```
"JARVIS Open Spotify" or "Hey Jarvis open spotify" or "Open spotify" or "launch spotify"
```

Is just `"JARVIS Open Spotify"`. Again, no need to use the `str` builtin.

Lastly, this is not the path for the `Spotify.exe`, I assume you tried to copy the path with `ctrl+shift+c` or similar command. The default executable can be found under `C:\Users\<Your_User>\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Spotify.exe`

Try to search for `Spotify.exe`, hold *shift*, right click on the `Spotify.exe` and click on *copy as path*